# Session Value not persisted in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Session not persisted in Azure App Service

I have a Web Application in Asp.net MVC, I used to set the session. When I click a LoginButton

```
Session["FlowType"] : "Auth"
```

Now the request goes to IdentityServer and during Callback on 
I tried to retrieve the session `Session["FlowType"]` and it gave me `null` value.

I checked the **Azure Affinity Cooki**e too. It is same, when I checked in fiddler.

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the strings is same like 'FlowType'.

Second,you can try to debug your code like below.

```
Session["FlowType"]="aaa";
string test = Session["FlowType"].ToString();
```

Check the value of 'test', is null or 'aaa'. If the value of test is correct,maybe you can print Ctrl+Alt+i to open the Immediate Window in Visual Studio. Then you can check when the Session is missing.

The last Step,maybe you can modfiy your web.config to set config about the Session. 
I hope the above answers can help you.

Add Pic
[image: Debug in azure]

How to debug in azure. You also can google it.

step 1: Make sure publish configuration setting. Like pic bellow

[image: publish configuration]

step 2: When publish succeed,you can attach debugger

1. My IDE is vs2019, you can click View-> Cloud Explore ,then you find you sourcegroup and web app.
2. Like pic, you find it , and click, it will show Attach Debugger, then you
   debugger in azure to test.

[image: How to find you attach app]
3. The first debugging will take a long time.

Comment: It works correctly when I am running it locally. But it gives null value when I deploy it on azure

Comment: I will modify my answer. It will add my pic about debugger in azure. It works fine about Session. Maybe you can debug too. I will add another answer about attach debug in azure.@AstroBoy

Comment: I have debugged my Azure App Service, using Attach debugger. but while retrieving the session value it always give me null value

Comment: According to my sample code, the usage of seesion should be OK on azure. It can be assigned and valued. Maybe your code has session related operations somewhere, which leads to the occurrence of the current problem. @AstroBoy

Comment: How long from assignment to you find session is missing ?@AstroBoy
Generally,  the session expiration time is 20min on IIS.  I haven't found any configuration on azure web yet.

Comment: If session missing immediately, pls check your code. 
Or you can set session expiration time in web.config.  Azure can read and use this configuration.@AstroBoy

Comment: Do you solve you problem？If it possible, you can crate a demo in github, I will be happy with you to solve this problem @AstroBoy

Comment: Thanks for you effort Jason, but its not yet resolved. The steps you mentioned I have already tried those. I will put my demo code on git hub

Comment: Okey, I'm willing to find the error with you. We can improve together@AstroBoy

Comment: @AstroBoy Did you ever figure out the resolution?